# Fetch word document from an API and download it

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a 3rd party API. When i call that api it will output a word document.

In my .net website i have an ASPX page. When user browse that page, i have to call that 3rd party API, get the word document and should send it to user as a downloadable word document.

***Note:*** I cannot call that 3rd party api using javascript for security reasons.

I tried below code

```
    WebClient wClient = new WebClient();
    var pagesource = wClient.DownloadString("3rd party api");

    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/msword");
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.docx");
    Response.Write(pagesource);
    Response.End();
```

It downloads the word document. But when i open it, it is corrupted.

Comment: If you are able to download that means the 'Download' worked. So my guess would be the source document is corrupted.  Are you facing the same issue for all documents that you have tested so far ?

Comment: Source document is good. When i try that 3rd party url directly in browser it is downloading properly.

Comment: in that case, please try the solution given by @LordJam

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the wClient.DownloadFile method?

Comment: @dbugger DownloadData works good as per accepted answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `wClient.DownloadString` is going to download the document as a string. You want to use `.DownloadData` to get the data as a byte array (binary). And then something like:

```
        var fileBytes = wClient.DownloadData("3rd party api");;

        if (fileBytes == null) return;

        string filename = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "-filename.docx";

        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileBytes.Length.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        //Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", filename)); // save file as attachment
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("inline; filename={0}", filename)); // display inline in browser
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
        Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure your mime type is incorrect for docx.  You are using the one for .doc.

Try

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
```

Comment: getting same error. File is corrupted and can not be opened.